# Create a satellite true color image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, rgb, satellite-image

I'm trying to create a true color RBG image from satellite data using matlab, but I don't know how to do it.

The false color RGB image is simple, just employing the right channels for the red, green and blue you can make it

```
    RGB(:,:,1)=(ref16)'; %red - reflectance 1.6mic
    RGB(:,:,2)=(ref06)'; %green - reflectance 600nm
    RGB(:,:,3)=(ref05)'; %blue - reflectance 500nm
    image(RGB)
```

In this case I'm using reflectances from the satellite channels which range from 0 to 1, so I don't need to modify the original data

But I'm having so much trouble when I try to plot true color images.

According to literature, the following profile should yield good RGB images from MERIS Level-1b data products (the data I'm using). The linear-combinations for the red, green and blue components are based on the colour matching functions of the CIE 1931 color space.

```
    RGB(:,:,1)=log(1.0+0.35*radiance_2+0.60*radiance_5+radiance_6+0.13*radiance_7)'
    RGB(:,:,2)=log(1.0+0.21*radiance_3+0.50*radiance_4+radiance_5+0.38*radiance_6)'
    RGB(:,:,3)=log(1.0+0.21*radiance_1+1.75*radiance_2+0.47*radiance_3+0.16*radiance_4)'
```

Radiance are real values going from 0 to 400 (with the scale factor applied), so I guess that I have to normalize the RGB array (0-1 or 0-255) to create the image.

But doing the normalization myself or just using im2uint8 doesn't produce the right image.

It's likely that I'm doing everything wrong because I'm not familiar with colour profiles. Is there a way in matlab to create the image using directly the CIE rgb combination (the one I think I'm getting from the above formulas)?

Is anyone out there familiar with images using matlab and satellite data?

Thanks!

Comment: May be this will help?   http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2015/05/06/matlab-used-to-map-earthquakes-from-satellite-data/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+mathworks%2Floren+%28Loren+on+the+Art+of+MATLAB%29

Comment: Not really, I think my main problem is the representation of CIE colour profiles using MATLAB, i.e. to create the RGB array using the CIE values. Thanks anyway!